# multiple entries for synchronous_standby_names

Tags: postgresql

Trying to achieve sync streaming to barman server and i need to add an entry to postgresql.conf for this parameter, which already has an entry and tried a few variations but does not work. Any ideas? Also tried '&&' but in vain

> synchronous_standby_names='ANY 1 (*)',barman-wal-archive
>
> 2022-06-10 16:50:54.272 BST [11241-43] @ app= LOG:  syntax error in
> file "/var/lib/pgsql/13/data/postgresql.conf" line 22, near token ","
> 2022-06-10 16:50:54.272 BST [11241-44] @ app= LOG:  configuration file
> "/var/lib/pgsql/13/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors; no changes
> were applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is not valid, and you won't be able to specify that Barman should be kept synchronous and any one of the others. The best you can do is

```
synchronous_standby_names = 'FIRST 2 ("barman-wal-archive", standby1, standby2, standby3)'
```

(You have to double quote all names that are not standard SQL identifiers, for example if they contain `-`.)

Then PostgreSQL will always keep Barman synchronized, as well as the first available standby server. But that won't have transactions fail if Barman is not available, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: still fails? 2022-06-13 09:41:36.700 BST [17115-11] @ app= LOG:  invalid value for parameter "synchronous_standby_names": "FIRST 2 (barman-wal-archive, rdbhelpgsl21p, rdbhelpgsl51p)"
2022-06-13 09:41:36.700 BST [17115-12] @ app= DETAIL:  syntax error at or near "-"

Comment: ive set it as below to overcome build errors but the sync to barman is still 'async'? `synchronous_standby_names='FIRST 2 ("barman-wal-archive", standby1, standby2)'
`

Comment: Sorry for the omission of adding quotes. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: barman replication-status still shows as async?

Comment: Then the `application_name` that shows up in `pg_stat_activity` is different from `barman-wal-archive`.

Comment: it is the same...

Comment: Is Barman running `pg_receivewal` there?

Comment: yes  `3. Async WAL streamer
     Application name: barman_receive_wal
     Sync stage      : 3/3 Remote write
     Communication   : TCP/IP
     IP Address      : 192.x.x.x / Port: 40040 / Host: -
     User name       : barman
     Current state   : streaming (async)
     Replication slot: barman_prd
     WAL sender PID  : 18392
     Started at      : 2022-06-10 18:16:02.514375+01:00
     Sent LSN   : 0/19001168 (diff: 0 B)
     Write LSN  : 0/19001168 (diff: 0 B)
     Flush LSN  : 0/19001168 (diff: 0 B)`

Comment: `barman_receive_wal` != `barman-wal-archive`

Comment: sorry dont understand. Apologies my experience is not at par and leaning along the way

Comment: I mean that your hard-to-read comment above suggests that `application_name` is different from what you said it was.

Answer (score 0):

Keep just

```
synchronous_standby_names='ANY 1 (*)'
```

and set

```
synchronous_commit = on
```

or

```
synchronous_commit = remote_write
```